# Custom source to field in Feeds module?

Tags: feeds, importing-exporting

I'm setting up a way for a Drupal site to import data from third party sites using a PHP script that creates a XML structure.

I'm using the Feeds module, which otherwise works fine. But I miss something.

Now, I need to add a custom source from the feed that adds data to a field.

Like that I have a  inside the XML  that I want to be used for the nodes image_field. I need more then just a image, but as an example.

How do I do that?

Is there perhaps a way that will work so that I wont have to code it by myself?

PS. Since I've coded the script that creates the XML, I could easily change XML to about anything else that might work better. DS.

Answer (score 5):

[Feeds Xpath Parser](http://drupal.org/project/feeds_xpathparser) module can help you map custom fields to your xml values.  I've used this myself.  There is also [Querypath Parser](http://drupal.org/project/feeds_querypath_parser) which may do the same thing (I've never tried this one).

Comment: It's a great module. I am using it with no problems

Answer (score 0):

Both *Feeds Xpath Parser* and *Querypath Parser* modules are near end-of-life on Drupal 7.  Going forward, use the XML (XPath) parser or the QueryPath XML parser from [Feeds extensible parser](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_ex) module for Drupal 8 and 9.